# SQL - Need to create extra rows with 'all' and replace in the two column with respective division

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, union, partition

I have a table in the snowflake that looks like below;

| Location | Device | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| DE | ios | 5 |
| DE | android | 6 |
| IT | ios | 3 |
| IT | android | 1 |

I create a query to reach my goal

```
select location,
       device,
       values
from tracking

union all

select 'all' as location
       'all' as device
       values
from tracking
```

so my output;

| Location | Device | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| all | all | 16 |
| DE | ios | 5 |
| DE | android | 6 |
| IT | ios | 3 |
| IT | android | 1 |

But, what I actually want, my desirable output;

| Location | Device | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| all | all | 16 |
| all | ios | 8 |
| all | android | 7 |
| DE | all | 11 |
| DE | ios | 5 |
| DE | android | 6 |
| IT | all | 4 |
| IT | ios | 3 |
| IT | android | 1 |

I hope it is clear what I want. I have a very complicated table with filters etc. So, I am looking very simple solution. If "union all" idea is already making complicated, I am totally okay to make changes there as well. I really appreciate any insights.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: I am using snowflake